# Beta Distribution Problem

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

So I have the made up situation where I have a coin of bias $0.4$ so the coin is slightly more likely to land on tails. Now, I have data where after $50$ flips, I get $18$ heads. So if I have the belief that the coin is fair then after $50$ flips, I should get $25$ heads and $25$ tails. So my prior would be

> Beta$(25,25)$

And that would make my posterior

> Beta$(25+18,25+32)$ $=$ Beta$(43,57)$

That's all good and I have plots in python for this. Now I want to say about if you choose a really bad prior like Beta$(40,10)$ which would make the posterior Beta$(58,42)$. I plot the graph and I get something off like I would expect.

Now the main question I want to ask is how can I then improve this? If I have a very poor prior like this and I plot the posterior, what can I do to improve the posterior? If I try just adding a scale factor like Beta$(58+20,42+20)$ kind of improves it but it doesn't bring the posterior close to the $\theta = 0.4$ line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayesian inference is based on taking both the prior distribution and the
data seriously. Each has its appropriate effect on the posterior distribution.
If you somehow know that the success probability is $\theta =0.4,$ then how do you arrive at the
prior distribution BETA(50, 50)?

Do you have knowledge of previous tosses
of the coin that showed half heads and half tails. If you just have a
vague feeling that the coin 'looks OK' after quick inspection, then maybe
the prior should be something like BETA(4, 4). If you just arrived from
Mars and don't even know what a 'coin' is, then maybe you would want a
non-informative prior like BETA(1,1) = UNIF(0,1) or BETA(.5, .5).

Posterior distributions BETA(43. 57) and BETA(58, 42) give the following
95% Bayesian probability intervals, respectively, using R. Notice that both intervals
contain success probability 0.5.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 43, 57)
[1] 0.3349894 0.5276638
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 58, 42)
[1] 0.4824441 0.6745238
```

Data from 1000 tosses of the coin would overwhelm either the priors you
propose; that is, the prior would not have much influence on the posterior. 
Finally, I have no idea what you mean by 'scale factor'.

Comment: Alright, I am doing investigation in computational bayesian analysis. So the bias of the coin would not be know but obviously I need one to aim for so I set this to $\theta = 0.4$. Now I have the data of $50$ flips and $18$ heads. And now, if i have no normal understanding like being from mars, I believe that if I flip 50 times and I will get 40 heads (which won't be true with a bias of $0.4$) is there no approach I can take to still be able to get a realistic posterior? and a scale factor is what I was meaning by adding a number to each like Beta$(58+40,42+40)$ to try and improve posterior.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to set exactly $\theta = 0.4.$ If you believe it's near 0.4, then pick a prior that concentrates probability in that vicinity. If you believe your prior and you believe the data are competently obtained, then logically you must believe the posterior. (Just like 2 + 3 = 5.) So in that sense the posterior is 'realistic'. If you aren't prepared to have the data  change your prior quite a bit in determining the posterior, than maybe you shouldn't be playing the 'Bayesian prior game'. Or like some politicians, just go with your prior opinion and ignore data altogether.

Comment: okay so you're saying that I would need to collect more data like 100 flips and then 200 flips to see the posterior and prior distributions get better even though the choice of prior is poor. I just want to visualise how a bad prior will affect the posterior and what would need to be done to improve it.

Comment: The effect of a 'bad' prior can be diluted by lots of data.